# yocto gobjection-inspection gLib2.0.typelib

Tags: yocto

How to cross-compile target images for **lib/girepository-1.0/GLib-2.0.typelib**

This due to recipe **python3-pyobject** enabled on my project, But Found I cannot *import GLib* from python3.
After tacked, follow up https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/gobject-introspection.html
but still cannot come out GLib-2.0.typelib from project.

- Checking variable MACHINE_FEATURES_XXX

```
$ grep ^MACHINE_FEATURES_  metadata.txt
MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL="rtc qemu-usermode"
MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED=" qemu-usermode rtc"
```

- Checking variable DISTRO_FEATURES_XXX

```
$ grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES_  metadata.txt
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL="pulseaudio sysvinit gobject-introspection-data ldconfig"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED=" pulseaudio sysvinit"
DISTRO_FEATURES_DEFAULT="acl alsa argp bluetooth ext2 ipv4 ipv6 largefile pcmcia usbgadget usbhost wifi xattr nfs zeroconf pci 3g nfc x11 vfat"
DISTRO_FEATURES_FILTER_NATIVE="  selinux"
DISTRO_FEATURES_FILTER_NATIVESDK="api-documentation"
DISTRO_FEATURES_NATIVE="x11 ipv6 xattr"
DISTRO_FEATURES_NATIVESDK="x11"
```

- Checking tasks

```
temp $ pwd
.../tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gobject-introspection/1.62.0-r0/temp   
temp $ cat log.task_order
do_populate_sysroot_setscene (6643): log.do_populate_sysroot_setscene.6643
do_package_write_ipk_setscene (6641): log.do_package_write_ipk_setscene.6641
do_package_qa_setscene (6640): log.do_package_qa_setscene.6640
do_populate_lic_setscene (6642): log.do_populate_lic_setscene.6642
do_rm_work (6644): log.do_rm_work.6644
do_packagedata_setscene (6690): log.do_packagedata_setscene.6690
```

Comment: If you have `qemu-usermode` in both `MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL` and `MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED`, then it won't end up in `MACHINE_FEATURES`. Try to remove it from `MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED`. See https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-MACHINE_FEATURES_BACKFILL